# How do I pass a parameter to an external function from inside STYLED-COMPONENTS using ReactJS with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

PS. The idea here is not to use the parameter directly in styled:
`opacity: ${(props) => props.myArr[0].myOpacity)}` .
The idea would be:

1. Pass a parameter (`myArray`) from any component to a **styled-components**:

```
<Wrap myArr={myArr}> ... <Wrap/>
```

2. Receive this parameter inside a styled:

```
export const Wrap = styled.div<{myArr: Object[]}>`
    //...
    ${ myFunc(props.myArr) } //<<< here my question
`;
```

3. Send this parameter to a function within the same file.

```
Function myFunc(myArr: Object[]) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thats very not how styled components works (refer to their docs), in this case `Wrap` should be a custom component which renders a styled element. In simple words: you can't do it.

Comment: Man, I managed to do it. Take a look [here...](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-forest-j7u5m?file=/src/styles.ts)

Comment: I understood it as you want to render a component from styled.div, i.e myFunc is a function component

Comment: Notice that you have utilities libs in docs section, for example `styled-tools` https://github.com/diegohaz/styled-tools has the same API as you asked